# Unnecessary assignment in do sequence

Tags: haskell

Let's look at:

```
instance (Error e) => MonadTrans (ErrorT e) where
  lift m = ErrorT $ do
    a <- m
    return (Right a)
```

I cannot understand why is necessary `a <- m`. Why we don't write just:

```
instance (Error e) => MonadTrans (ErrorT e) where
  lift m = ErrorT $ do
    return (Right m)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
m :: m a
Right m :: Either e (m a)
return (Right m) :: m (Either e (m a))
ErrorT $ return (Right m) :: ErrorT e m (m a)
```

This has the wrong type: we wanted `ErrorT e m a`.

Instead, when using `a <- m`, we have:

```
a :: a
Right a :: Either e a
return (Right a) :: m (Either e a)
ErrorT $ return (Right a) :: ErrorT e m a
```

which is OK.

(Above some value variables have the same name of type variables on the right of `::` -- this is just an incident.)

Alternatives:

```
instance (Error e) => MonadTrans (ErrorT e) where
  lift m = ErrorT $ fmap Right m
```

or with applicative notation,

```
instance (Error e) => MonadTrans (ErrorT e) where
  lift m = ErrorT $ Right <$> m
```

Comment: From first your piece of code: `return (Right m) :: *m* (Either e (m a))`
I cannot understand why it is m ( I highlighted it by *m* ) and not for example `ErrorT`

Comment: @Gilgamesz You are correct: that it is actually `n (Either e (m a))` for any monad `n`, which can be different from `m`. The final result would then be `ErrorT ... :: ErrorT e n (m a)`, but since `lift` must return `ErrorT e m a`, this forces `n = m` (and `m a = a`, which is impossible and triggers a type error). I applied `n = m` earlier, being a bit less general. (and by the same token, `Right a` should be `Either z a` for all `z` including those different from `e` ... but eventually `z` must be `e` anyway)

Answer (score 4):

You're reading `a <- m` as "assign `a` the value `m`." That notation for assignment is common in pseudocode, but it means something different in Haskell. You can read it as "Produce a value from `m` and bind that value to `a`." To be more precise, in a `do` block,

```
a <- m
...
...
```

is equivalent to

```
m >>= \a ->
  do
    ...
    ...
```

So applying `Right` to `a` is sensible, but applying it to `m` gives you a monadic action wrapped in `Either`, which isn't usually what you're after.

There *is*, however, a shorter way to write that instance:

```
instance Error e => MonadTrans (ErrorT e) where
  lift m = ErrorT (Right <$> m)
```

Nota Bene: `ErrorT` has generally been supplanted by the more generally-useful `ExceptT`, which doesn't have the annoying and often-irrelevant `Error` context. In particular, it's very often useful to have an "exception" value that doesn't actually represent an error and isn't an instance of `Show`.